# How to set a base URL for NodeJs applications using ExpressJs server and AngularJs for frontend?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

I want to add a base URL to my application when I load it on my browser.

My expressJs config is:

> App.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(expressSanitizer());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/webapp'));
app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

AngularJs router config:

> index.js

```
$urlRouterProvider
        .when('','login')
        .when('/','login')
        .otherwise(function($injector, $location){
            var state= $injector.get('$state');
            state.go('error', { url: $location.path() }, { location: true });
        });

        //define states
        $stateProvider
        .state('/',{
            templateUrl: 'public/login.html',
            controller: 'login',
            authenticated:false
        })
        .state('login',{
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'public/login.html',
            authenticated:false
            // controller: 'login'
            // template: '<h1> Routing to login page </h1>'
        })
```

I want it similar to that when we deploy application in Apache Tomcat.

Currently when I start the server the url is like `localhost:8080/login` but I want it as `localhost:8080/CRM/login`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out the solution in this way.

I added a base tag in my index.html and added '/CRM' in all my api's in my App.js

> index.html

```
<base href="/CRM/">
```

> App.js

```
app.use('/CRM/users',appRoutes);
```

Comment: <base href="/CRM/"> works for me